# How do I access data from MongoDB of an existing database using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to access the data of a MongoDB Database using Mongoose. In every Mongoose Tutorial, we first need to create a schema and then a model out of it. But, I already have the data in the database. What I m trying s creating an empty schema and passing the collection name as the third parameter while creating the model out of it. But for some unknown reason I can't access the data, when I import the model class in another file.
Model File:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Create a Schema
const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false });

const Company = mongoose.model("Company", CompanySchema, "companies");
// console.log(Company)

module.exports = Company;
```

NOTE: Companies is the name of collection I wanna access, see image.
[db image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeFVX.png)

In this file I m just trying to read the data:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Companies = require('../models/Companies')

// Homepage Route
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('home'))

// List Route
router.get('/list', (req, res) =>
  res.render('list')
);

// Register Route
router.get('/register', (req, res) =>
  res.render('register')
);

console.log(Companies.find({}))

module.exports = router;
```

The console gives me this (I think it's a mongoose object):

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: NativeCollection {
    collection: null,
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      schemaUserProvidedOptions: [Object],
      capped: false,
      autoCreate: undefined,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'companies',
    collectionName: 'companies',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 0,
      _closeCalled: false,
      _hasOpened: false,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,
      _listening: false
    },
    queue: [],
    buffer: true,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  model: Model { Company },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: {},
    paths: { _id: [ObjectId], __v: [SchemaNumber] },
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {},
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: {},
    methodOptions: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: { _id: [Object], __v: [Function: Number], id: [VirtualType] },
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    '$id': 1,
    s: { hooks: [Kareem] },
    _userProvidedOptions: { strict: false },
    options: {
      strict: false,
      typePojoToMixed: true,
      typeKey: 'type',
      id: true,
      noVirtualId: false,
      _id: true,
      noId: false,
      validateBeforeSave: true,
      read: null,
      shardKey: null,
      autoIndex: null,
      minimize: true,
      discriminatorKey: '__t',
      versionKey: '__v',
      capped: false,
      bufferCommands: true,
      pluralization: true
    },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true
  },
  op: 'find',
  options: {},
  _conditions: {},
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: NativeCollection {
      collection: null,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'companies',
      collectionName: 'companies',
      conn: [NativeConnection],
      queue: [],
      buffer: true,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    },
    collectionName: 'companies'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Return type of Model.find({}) is Query so it gives such output.but if you want all document as output then you have to use call back function

```
Companies.find({}, function (err, docs) {
                         console.log(docs)
                        });
```

Comment: Please accept any answer if it solve your problem so it will help other people with similar problem.[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)